# facebook login works on iphone simulator but not on iphone device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

In my app, I want to take photos from the facebook. so i used facebook ios sdk. i can be able to authorize from the below code:

```
 if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

            //[appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [self retrieveAlbums];

        } else {
            if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
                // Create a new, logged out session.
                appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
            }

            // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
            [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState status,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
                //NSLog(@"%@",session.accessTokenData.accessToken);
                [self retrieveAlbums];
            }];
```

It works fine on iphone simulator. But I can't able to login on my iphone 4 device.
When I tried to login it will open a safari and then shows the message Updating.
Then it will redirect without authorization. access token retrieved as nil. So I cant able to retreive images.

Please help me.

> **EDIT**

Thanks for everyone .Finally I solved my problem. It is because i enabled sandbox mode in facebook developer account settings. When i disabled the sandbox mode, it works normally.

Comment: What is the iOS version of iPhone4

Comment: Hey @manujmv, I am having the similar problem. Disabling sandbox mode does not mean this issue is solved because sooner or later we will enable it.

Comment: @ZaferFatihKoyuncu but my app works perfectly untill now

Comment: I made it work in sandbox mode yesterday. I will post it today.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the cookies and cache of your safari, going to Settings.
Also if you do not want the app to redirect to Safari, just dont provide the URL Scheme in your info.plist that is something like "fb-AppId-" and it will open a popup for login

Answer (score 0):

I was having the similar problem and solved it by composing couple of solutions in this website. First of all I got rid of the url scheme at my info plist. So now my app opens up the facebook login dialog inside my registration page. Which is a good thing because it doesn't go back and forth to safari for facebook authentication and you stay inside the app. The second thing I made is, putting an error handling mechanism inside my code for facebook login. So if login with facebook fails, it uses another strategy for logging in.

Here is my code.

```
  - (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {

      NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"public_profile", @"user_friends", @"email",
                        nil];
      FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
      [FBSession setActiveSession:session];

      [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
         if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
           NSString *token = session.accessTokenData.accessToken;
           NSLog(@"Logged in! - Token -- %@", token);
         } else {
           NSLog(@"Something wrong happened");//you can check the error code here
         }
     }];
  }
```